# Разобрать логику функции

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, загружаю изображение через инпут и тут же вывожу эту картинку, но ни как не могу понять, как она работает (под цифрами буду писать вопросы):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fch(f) { //(1) почему в аргументе передаётся f и откуда она вообще взялась?
            var fls = f.files; // (2)f оказывается объект...но мы же нигде не создавали объект? 
            if (!fls || !fls.length || !FileReader) { (3)// тут более менее, если это не true.... но что такое FileReader?
                return;
            }
            var fr = new FileReader(); //создаём объект
            fr.onload = function() { // добавляем свойство
                var im = new Image();
                im.src = this.result;
                var d = document.getElementById('imgp');
                d.replaceChild(im, d.firstChild);
            };
            fr.readAsDataURL(fls[0]);
        }
    </script>
    <input type="file" onchange="fch(this);" />
    <div id="imgp">img</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `f` - это параметр, который вы передаёте при вызове функции, в данном случае это `this` в строке:  `<input type="file" onchange="fch(this);" />`
2. `this` при загрузке файла это объект с данным файла, вроде бы, имя и расширение.
3. `!FileReader` это проверка вашего браузера на возможность работы с API файлов, подробнее [тут](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)